# Trying to set "background-color=dark" but error is : E492: Not an editor command: background=dark

Tags: vim

In GVIM first let's

```
File ---> Color Scheme --> desert
```

okay now let's find out what this setting equates to by typing

```
:set
```

I see the first line that reads

```
background-color=dark
```

so let's create a file named

```
 /root/.vimrc
```

and place that line in it and reload GVIM.

Here is the full error:

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc: 
line    1: 
E492: Not an editor command: background=dark
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
set background=dark
```

The other is an ill formed command.

You can put any ex command in your vimrc by dropping the `:`. So instead of typing `:set background=dark` on the command line you put `set background=dark` in your vimrc.

However this command should not be in your vimrc. It should be set by your colorscheme.

---

The first part of your question seems to be how do I set the colorscheme desert from the command line. Well the command is `:colorscheme desert`.

So if you want to restore the desert colorscheme everytime you load vim you can put

```
colorscheme desert
```

in your vimrc. (`/root/.vimrc` in this case)